# Why Python function executes when not called?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am a student learning Python. I have a program for working with an array:

```
from array import *

adj_list = array('i', [])

def includeNode():
    print('Enter the value')
    k = int(input())
    adj_list.append(k)
    print('Your list:')
    printList()

def includeNodeIndex():
    print('Enter the value')
    k = int(input())
    print('Enter the index')
    index = int(input())
    adj_list.insert(index, k)
    print('Your list:')
    printList()

def deleteNode():
    print('Enter the value')
    k = int(input())
    adj_list.remove(k)
    print('Your list:')
    printList()

def printList():
    for i in adj_list:
        print(i)

actions = {
    '1': includeNode(),
    '2': includeNodeIndex(),
    '3': deleteNode()
}

print('Enter the number of elements')
num = int(input())

print('Enter ', num, ' elements')
for i in range(num):
    k = int(input())
    includeNode(k)

print('Your list:')
printList()

print('Enter 0 to exit. Enter 1 to delete an element. Enter 2 to add an element. Enter 3 to insert an element after index')
command = input()
while(command):
   actions[command]
   print('Enter 0 to exit. Enter 1 to delete an element. Enter 2 to add an element. Enter 3 to insert an element after index')
   command = input()
```

I expect that when I execute the code, it will output `Enter the number of elements` and then I'll be able to work with my array. But this doesn't happen. Instead, the program outputs `Enter the value`: it means that it executes the `includeNode()` function which I haven't even called!
Why does it happen so? Shouldn't this function be executed when it's called (not when it's declared)?

Comment: You call it there: `actions = {
    '1': includeNode(),
    '2': includeNodeIndex(),
    '3': deleteNode()
}`

Comment: You also don't need to use the `array` module. You might be coming from other languages, where an "array" is how you normally represent an array of things. In Python, [we have/use `lists`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you put the parenthesis, you're actually calling the functions when building `actions` dict, so

```
actions = {
    '1': includeNode,
    '2': includeNodeIndex,
    '3': deleteNode
}

actions['1']()
```

---

`input` allows the a text parameter to be shown to the use that allows the following simplification

```
print('Enter the value')
k = int(input())

# into
k = int(input('Enter the value: '))
```

Giving things like

```
info_txt = 'Enter 0 to exit. Enter 1 to delete an element. Enter 2 to add an element. Enter 3 to insert an element after index'
command = input(info_txt)
while command:
    actions[command]()
    command = input(info_txt)
```

But careful the info text DOESN'T match the `actions` dict key mapping